# How to get rid of from overbooking car rental website

Tags: customization

I have a car rent site where people can book a car for their needs. The problem is my vehicles are limited so after booking a car I want to immediately show an alert for the next 1 hour that it is overbooked so no one can book it again within that hour.

Here is my approach-

- Fetching only today's booking info
- Checking whether every vehicle is booked or not
- If it is booked, then count the booking time and current time and
  compare them. Is it equal to or less then 1 hour?
- If it returns true then show the alert

Now problem is how can I remove this message after 1 hour?

Any code example would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your question, but... How is that connected with WordPress exactly?

Comment: How did you checked and show the message?

Answer (score 1):

Guys found the solution at `**stackoverflow**`:

You can use `set_transient` function after someone booked a car. I assume a car is post type and all post have a unique ID. So after a car is booked you create a transient which expires after one hour. [Check Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/). Your code might have the next logic.

```
set_transient( $post_id . '_car_is_booked', true, HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
```

You set transient for `HOUR_IN_SECONDS` it is a special WordPress variable and after one hour it will be removed from the database automatically. So to find our is this car is booked or not you can use function `get_transient` [get_transient Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_transient).

```
// return false if option does not exists 
get_transient( $post_id . '_car_is_booked' );
```

And if `transient` for specific post ID exists it means the car is booked less then one hour ago.